# How to get username of Instagram account

Tags: python, html

I want to know how I can print the username of the Instagram account by the link the user will provide using python. Image attached for better understanding.

[image]

Comment: The instagram url would be of the form "instagram.com-slash-{username}". So you could split on '/' and grab the last element of the array.

Comment: Instead of focusing on a picture of the UI where you would type your input, focus on *your actual input*.  What value do you have, and what information are you trying to extract from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, the Instagram link should be something like this:

`link = "https://www.instagram.com/instagram"`

What you can do, is split the string using `/` as separator, which turns it into a list, and from there get the last value of it:

`username = link.split('/')[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let url = "https://instagram.com/username".split("/")
let username = url[url.length - 1]
```

Comment: Typo. Fixed. We answered at the same time.